# How return a list of number without iter?

Tags: python, loops, numbers, int

hi so i want to know how to get a list of number with a loop

Exemple i try it

```
i = 1
while i <= 5:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
```

but he iter the number like this

```
1

2

3

4

5
```

and this is what i want

```
i = 1 
while i <= 5:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1

1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5
```

so what i have to do

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print(*range(1, 6), sep=' , ')
1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5
```

You don't need a loop for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can replace the `print(i)` with `print(i, end=" , ")` at the 3rd line of your code

Also, I think Ravan's solution to your problem is more pythonic.